# Does 1 Kings 8:27 mean that God cannot dwell on earth?

Tags: exegesis, 1-kings

1 Kings 8:27 (ESV):

“But will God indeed dwell on the earth? Behold, heaven and the highest heaven cannot contain you; how much less this house that I have built!"

It seems like the text is saying that God cannot dwell on earth (or even in heaven) but that doesn't sound right. What is really going on here?